# Prove the following ceiling and floor identities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Could someone help me prove these identities? I'm completely lost:

$$\begin{align*}
&(1)\quad \left\lceil \frac{\left\lceil \frac{x}{a} \right\rceil} {b}\right\rceil = \left\lceil {\frac{x}{ab}}\right\rceil\\\\
&(2)\quad\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{a} \right\rfloor} {b}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor {\frac{x}{ab}}\right\rfloor\\\\
&(3)\quad \left\lceil {\frac{a}{b}} \right\rceil \le \frac{a + b - 1}{b}\\\\
&(4)\quad \left\lfloor {\frac{a}{b}} \right\rfloor \ge \frac{a - b + 1}{b}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Any assumptions on $a,b$?

Comment: For any real $n \geq 0$ and integers $a,b>0$

Answer (score 12):

Using the *universal* properties of floor and ceiling makes such proofs mechanical, e.g.

$\rm {\bf Lemma}\quad\ \lfloor x/(mn)\rfloor = \lfloor{\lfloor x/m\rfloor}/n\rfloor\quad for\ \ \ n > 0 $

$\rm\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf Proof}\quad\ &&\rm\ \ k &\,\le&\rm \lfloor{\lfloor x/m\rfloor}/n\rfloor\\ \\
&\iff\ &\rm \ \ k &\,\le&\rm \ \, {\lfloor x/m\rfloor}/n\\ \\
&\iff\ &\rm nk &\,\le&\rm\ \,\lfloor x/m\rfloor \\ \\
&\iff\ &\rm nk &\,\le&\rm\ \ \, x/m \\ \\
&\iff\ &\rm\ \  k &\,\le&\rm\ \ \, x/(mn)\\ \\
&\iff\ &\rm\ \   k &\,\le&\rm\ \lfloor x/(mn)\rfloor
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: This doesn’t prove equality but only that RHS is less than LHS and hence k <= LHS when it is <= RHS.

Comment: Yes it does, each <=> is an if and only if, not an implication =>. Hence, it can be read top down or bottom up. Read top down: for any k <= RHS, it's also <= LHS means RHS >= LHS Read bottom up: for any k <= LHS, it's also <= RHS means LHS >= RHS Hence, since RHS >= LHS and LHS >= RHS, this means LHS = RHS 
Each relation is correctly written as an if and only if relation instead of just an implication relation because k is an integer, not a real number.

Comment: To be specific, the upper bound for the real number k is an integer since it starts off from both ends from the floor function => upper bounded by an integer.

Answer (score 9):

You can work directly from the definitions. I’ll do $(2)$ and $(3)$ to illustrate.

$(2)$ First note that you want $a$ and $b$ to be positive. If not, you might have $x=\frac12$ and $a=b=-1$, in which case the lefthand side is $$\left\lfloor-\left\lfloor-\frac12\right\rfloor\right\rfloor=\lfloor-(-1)\rfloor=1\;,$$ and the righthand side is $\left\lfloor\frac12\right\rfloor=0$. You also want them to be integers: if $x=2$ and $a=b=\sqrt2$, the lefthand side is $$\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor\sqrt2\rfloor}{\sqrt2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac1{\sqrt2}\right\rfloor=0\;,$$ and the righthand side is $1$. I will assume, then, that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Let $m=\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}a\right\rfloor$ and $n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{ab}\right\rfloor$. Then $$m\le\frac{x}a<m+1\quad\text{and}\quad n\le\frac{x}{ab}<n+1\;,\tag{1}$$ and you need to show that $\left\lfloor\dfrac{m}b\right\rfloor=n$, i.e., that $$n\le\frac{m}b<n+1\;.\tag{2}$$ Divide the first inequality in $(1)$ by $b$ to get $$\frac{m}b\le\frac{x}{ab}<\frac{m}b+\frac1b\;,$$ where $b\ge 1$. Now what would happen if $(2)$ failed? That would mean that either $\frac{m}b<n$, or $\frac{m}b\ge n+1$. It’s not hard to show that both are impossible. Suppose first that $\frac{m}b<n$. Then $\frac{m}b\le n-\frac1b$. (Why? Use the fact that $m,n$, and $b$ are integers.) Thus, $$\frac{x}{ab}<\frac{m}b+\frac1b\le n\;,$$ contradicting the second inequality in $(1)$. And if $\frac{m}b\ge n+1$, then $$\frac{x}{ab}\ge\frac{m}b\ge n+1\;,$$ again contradicting that inequality. So $(2)$, which is exactly what we set out to prove, must be true.

---

$(3)$ Let $m=\left\lceil\dfrac{a}b\right\rceil$, so that $m-1<\dfrac{a}b\le m$. Because $a,b$, and $m-1$ are integers, $$\frac{a}b-(m-1)\ge\frac1b\;,$$ and therefore $$m\le\frac{a}b+1-\frac1b=\frac{a+b-1}b\;,$$ which is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: Hi there. Could you please explain how did you get to this: $\frac{a}b-(m-1)\ge\frac1b\;$?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi: If $\frac{a}b=m$, then $\frac{a}b-(m-1)=1\ge\frac1b$, so assume that $\frac{a}b<m$. Then $b(m-1)<a<bm$, so $1\le a-b(m-1)$, and therefore $\frac1b\le\frac{a}b-(m-1)$.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi: As I said, that’s true when $\frac{a}b=m$: just subtract $m-1$ from both sides.

Comment: But isn't m considered as $m=\left\lceil\dfrac{a}b\right\rceil$

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi: Yes. When $\frac{a}b$ is an integer, that integer is its ceiling. E.g., $\left\lceil\frac62\right\rceil=3$.

Comment: Ohh I see. But as we all know an integer is usually the floor value of the fraction. Like a computer program irrespective of the programming language stores a floor value in integer so it usually stores the floor value instead of the ceiling one. Please clear my this doubt. It seems to be the last one.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi: I really don’t understand what your question is. In this problem we’re working with the ceiling function, not the floor function; the floor function has nothing to do with the problem. (And programming languages also have nothing to do with the problem.)

Comment: Sure. I got the answer. Thank you so much once again. I was really confused on the concepts. :)

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi: You’re welcome.

Comment: Logic behind $\frac{m}{b} < n$ implies  $\frac{m}{b}+ \frac{1}{b}\leq n$ is like this, $m,n,b$ are integers and $b>1$ so $m<nb$ without any change in the direction of equality. Now the LHS and RHS of the inequality are integers. So $m+1\leq nb$. Now dividing the inequality throughout by $b$ we have $\frac{m}{b}+ \frac{1}{b}\leq n$. Just noted this here lest I forget it...